# HTML5 Sqlite backup

Tags: iphone, ajax, html, sqlite, remote-backup

I'm creating a on offline web application with jqueryMobile (not using phonegap).
Everythng it's ok on the client side, the DB works good, but I'm wondering **how to backup data**.

The app is not meant to be public, I've created for me, for a personal purpose, so **it's important for me to backup and restore data**.

Do you know any solution?

I was thinking on:

1 - create a sqlite dump of my local iphone database, then pushing the object via AJAX to a PHP page hosted on my hosting server online that will elaborate it and save the data on MYSQL.

2 - Using iCloud or Dropbox (but I have no idea on how to do it)

What do you think about it?
Am I on the wrong way?

Thank you so much

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your APP is running on your Iphone.

In your case i would..

1) Run a SELECT * FROM 
2) Put that data into an object
3) Send the object with Ajax to your PHP 
4) Parse the data and convert it to standard SQL and save it to your disk

Im sure that there are many other "ways" to do this, but im sure this is bound to be a dirty method :)